# How to add custom property on electron js browsel window?

Tags: electron

I tried adding a custom property on the main browser window, but when tried to access i am just getting undefined.

Upon the creation of the main window I add a custom property.

```
let win = new electron.BrowserWindow();
win.sampleProperty = 'sample value';
```

But when accessing it cant retrieve the value of the `sampleProperty`.

```
let bw = browserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
console.log(bw.sampleProperty) // This is undefined
```

I'd used the `getFocusedWindow()` because it will be triggered on menu click.

What I am missing here why `bw.sampleProperty` is undefined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I just end app adding the property to the `browserWindowOptions`

This is how to do it:

Upon on creation of the `browserWindow` just add your property on the constructor.

```
let win = new electron.BrowserWindow({
  show: false,
  customProperty: 'sample' // And here it is.
});
```

Then you can access it on the `browserWindowOptions`

```
let customProp = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()
                 .webContents
                 .browserWindowOptions.customProperty;
```

Comment: Last line has a couple typos. Should be: let customProp = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().webContents.browserWindowOptions.customProperty;

Comment: It seem like 'browserWindowOptions' is no longer exist under webContents